# Idle time calculation_Anylogic Agent

Tags: anylogic

How can i calculate idle time for all the agents entering through source and exiting into the sink.
I want to get these data as a table( agentID vs idle time) as well as in a plot which gives average idle time.
I don't know much java either and this is my first assignment in anylogic. Learning through you tube videos.

Comment: There are a million ways to do it. But first, you need to define what "idle" means in your model. Then, record block enter/exit times within your agent, do the calcs and finally, write it into a table. Probably, each of those steps is an individual question for you here on SOF, as this is (again) far too broad :) See https://www.benjamin-schumann.com/blog/2021/4/1/how-to-win-at-anylogic-on-stackoverflow

Comment: You can add idle time as one of the parameters of your agent. Than when entering a block you can use the code part of this flowchart block to change this parameters. You can use the time of the simulation by using the time() function. So for example when something enters a block and the block before was the idle time you just use agent.IdleTime=Time()-Timearrival, where timearrival can be another parameter you trace during the flowchart.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.